# How can I stop a for loop with a condition? [Python]

Tags: python, selenium, loops

I have this for loop:

```
for word in words_letter_list:
            text_input.send_keys(word)
            time.sleep(1)
            text_input.send_keys(u'\ue007')
```

This loop takes a set of words and writes them into a textarea (using Selenium Chrome webdriver)

In addition I have this loop:

```
for text in current_word:
        if '_' in current_word_text:
            print('write')
        else:
            break
```

**I want the first for loop to stop if the current_word contains no longer "_".**

How is it possible?

Comment: Can you please clarify what you are asking? Your question shows that you already know how to stop a loop based on a condition.

Comment: But I don't know how to mix these two loops

Comment: how is the two loops related

Comment: Post an example list contained in `words_letter_list` and `current_word`. Then write out an explanation (using words) of what you want this script to do because right now it's not clear.

Answer (score 2):

You'll need nested for loops then.

```
for text in current_word:
    if not '_' in current_word_text:
        break
    for word in words_letter_list:
        text_input.send_keys(word)
        time.sleep(1)
        text_input.send_keys(u'\ue007')
```

Comment: This doesn't work, because I search the "_" in another word from another for loop

Comment: I just modified my answer for your comment. If it is not the solution then please try to make your post more clear or please add the missing code.